# FOP throws "IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute" when running in a jar

Tags: spring-boot, pdf-generation, apache-fop

I am using Spring Boot and FOP to generate PDF and send back to UI components. When I run the Spring Boot application with "mvn spring-boot:run" everything works fine (PDF is generated on the fly and rendered in the UI), however, if I package this spring boot application in a jar and run it by "java -jar xxx.jar", I have encountered the following error raised by FOP:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1088)
at org.apache.fop.fonts.FontDetectorFactory$DefaultFontDetector.detect(FontDetectorFactory.java:94)
at org.apache.fop.fonts.FontManager.autoDetectFonts(FontManager.java:229)
at org.apache.fop.fonts.DefaultFontConfigurator.configure(DefaultFontConfigurator.java:82)
at org.apache.fop.render.PrintRendererConfigurator.getCustomFontCollection(PrintRendererConfigurator.java:147)
at org.apache.fop.render.PrintRendererConfigurator.setupFontInfo(PrintRendererConfigurator.java:127)
at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFUtil.setupFonts(IFUtil.java:170)
at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.setupFontInfo(IFRenderer.java:187)
at org.apache.fop.area.RenderPagesModel.<init>(RenderPagesModel.java:75)
at org.apache.fop.area.AreaTreeHandler.setupModel(AreaTreeHandler.java:135)
at org.apache.fop.area.AreaTreeHandler.<init>(AreaTreeHandler.java:105)
at org.apache.fop.render.RendererFactory.createFOEventHandler(RendererFactory.java:350)
at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.<init>(FOTreeBuilder.java:107)
at org.apache.fop.apps.Fop.createDefaultHandler(Fop.java:104)
at org.apache.fop.apps.Fop.<init>(Fop.java:78)
at org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent.newFop(FOUserAgent.java:182)
at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newFop(FopFactory.java:240)
```

...

FopFactory is created with an InputStream of a config file (fop.xconf) in one line:

```
fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(fopConfig.getURI(),fopConfig.getInputStream());
Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);
```

I suspect the exception is related to the Font configuration in the fop.xconf, where I've put two lines to add Chinese fonts support:

```
    <font kerning="yes" embed-url="/Users/matrix/Library/Fonts/msyh.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
      <font-triplet name="MicrosoftYaHei" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    </font>
    <font kerning="yes" embed-url="/Users/matrix/Library/Fonts/msyhbd.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
      <font-triplet name="MicrosoftYaHei" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
    </font>
```

My questions are: 
1) Is this really an issue related to the font configuration in the fop.xconf file?

2) If it is, how can I resolve this?

3) Is there a better way for FOP to support Chinese fonts, e.g. leverage the system fonts installed on the host machine rather than hard-coded font configuration for each font family.

Thanks so much for help.

Comment: Can you share a complete minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Let me offer a couple of comments: Your embed-url values are indeed relative-path URLs, so those fonts will only be successfully found if the process is working from just the right location on the system, not a really robust way to specify where they are located. You might also back up a step to confirm the error (per your question 1) by taking those <font lines out temporarily, and see if the error(s) go away. Consolidating your fonts in one known location can simplify your resource management quite a bit.

Comment: @acg_so Suggestions are taken. The embedded urls are absolute path (I am using a  Mac so that's the absolute paths of the font files). It looks like different classloaders that caused this problem. Spring boot application, if running as a jar, uses LaunchedURLClassLoader, however, if running using "mvn spring-boot:run", the classloader used is a standard java.net.URLClassLoader. I am trying to isolate the issue by removing some configurations from fop.xconf. Will report if I have some progress.

Answer (score 3):

After some digging, the issue is solved. It is because of the different classloaders used by Spring Boot when running spring boot applications in different modes, e.g, run as a jar or run as a web application. The following is the change I made to solve this problem:

```
<font kerning="yes" embed-url="file:/Users/matrix/Library/Fonts/msyh.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
  <font-triplet name="MicrosoftYaHei" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
</font>
<font kerning="yes" embed-url="file:/Users/matrix/Library/Fonts/msyhbd.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
  <font-triplet name="MicrosoftYaHei" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
</font>
```

Please note the "file:" used in the embedded url. That's the key to solve this problem.

Because of the different classloaders, I have encountered same issue when I used <fo:external-graphic> in my xslt stylesheet. Depending on what classloader is used, fop may not find the external image with a relative path. So I have to use an absolute url starting with "http" and make my images as public resources, which is OK with me because they are logos and icons.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute) when I referenced fonts from resources (embed-url="/fonts/times.ttf"). Prefixing it with "classpath:" (embed-url="classpath:/fonts/times.ttf") fixed the problem and FOP could find the font correctly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24709283)

Comment: Is there a way I can provide this information under this specific thread? My comment can be helpful for someone else facing the same error message with combination of Apache FOP although it doesn't provide an answer to main question. I would appreciate such information when I was looking for the solution. I couldn't find the solution anywhere - my colleague helped me.